# how the physical layer knows a bit received is from a specific packet?

Tags: networking, tcp

E.g. two bits are sent at the same time from two different packets through a same physical layer

how does it manage it

Comment: It doesn't care. Packets is an abstraction of a higher layer.

Comment: Off-topic, since not about programming. And the details depend on the specific physical layer. But to get some idea have a look at [CSMA/CD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-sense_multiple_access_with_collision_detection) which is used to detect for example in Ethernet to manage such collisions between multiple senders on a shared medium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *physical layer* encodes *bits* to symbols and decodes them back. It has no concept of frames, packets or anything from the higher layers.

The *data link layer* knows which bits belong to the same *frame* because they are between a start-of-frame and an end-of-frame.

The *network layer* is passed the data link layer's payload and interprets those data chunks as *packets*.